# Autocomplete doesn't trigger on second focusing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, focus

I'm trying to trigger autocomplete list on focus or click event. This solution helps, but when i click input field second time, nothing happens: list doesn't appear.

```
$('input').autocomplete({
  source: ["1","2"],
  minLength: 0 
}).focus(function(){
  $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
});
```

i tried this variant - no good

```
$(this).keydown();
```

this line works well in same place:

```
$(this).attr('value,new Date());
```

p.s. jQuery UI 1.8.16, jQuery v1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
$('input').autocomplete({
  source: ["1","2"],
  minLength: 0 
}).focus(function(){
  $(this).autocomplete('search');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('input').autocomplete({
  source: ["1","2"],
  focus: function(){ $(this).autocomplete('search'); },
  minLength: 0 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the field is already focussed then the focus event won't be called, try this:

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: ["1","2"],
    minLength: 0 
}).focus(function(){
    $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
}).click(function(){
    $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
});
```

Which duplicates some code, this may get messy with anything more than the simple one-liner that you have; if it does you could improve it by pulling out the function like so:

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: ["1","2"],
    minLength: 0 
}).focus(myfocus).click(myfocus);
function myfocus (e){
    $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');              
}
```